# Why am I getting an Rate limit exceeded error 88 from the twitter api?

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I'm only sending a request for 4 tweets from my own timeline. According to the twitter site I should be able to receive several hundred tweets every 15 minutes with my v2 Standard Basic access account.
I don't see how I'm reaching that limit by requesting 4 tweets, and my twitter account itself only has 18 tweets (don't know if those are even included since I only request 4 of them).

I'll show my code so you can see how I'm using the Twitter API.

This is the function that gets the 4 tweets:

```
def toon_tweets():
r = api.request('statuses/home_timeline', {'count':4})
tweet_lijst = []
for item in r.get_iterator():
    if 'text' in item:
        tweet_lijst.append(item['text'])

return tweet_lijst
```

I call this function from another app in the following manner:

```
tweets_label = Label(root,fg = "#0313fc" , bg = "#ffcc00",
            #text = ns_m3_testB.toon_tweets(),
            text = "{}\n {}\n {}\n {}".format(ns_m3_testB.toon_tweets()[0], ns_m3_testB.toon_tweets()[1], ns_m3_testB.toon_tweets()[2], ns_m3_testB.toon_tweets()[3]),    
            font = "none 14 bold",
            justify = "left")
```

I'm at a loss how such a simple request can cause me to exceed the rate limit.

Comment: Currently, you’re not using the v2 API, even if your app has access to it. The home_timeline endpoint is currently v1.1 only. Also, what you’re retrieving here is your *home* timeline, which is the timeline of Tweets from users you follow that you see when you are signed into Twitter, not the one you see when visiting a user page. So it’s likely that you could exceed the rate limit for calls depending on how fast your code loops (v1.1 is limited on number of calls in 15 minutes).

Comment: The v1 has an even higher limit. My account follows nobody so in essence its only my tweets. So since i placed a small amount of tweets how can it reech the limit?

Comment: I would have to test it, but since there is no paging, your code will repeatedly retrieve the most recent 4 Tweets. What’s the time between calls to the API? I’m pretty sure you get 15 calls in a 15 minute window to home_timeline, you can check the `x-rate-limit-limit` HTTP header to confirm. The user_timeline endpoint is more generous and would be more efficient.

Comment: How frequently does the following code get executed: `           text = "{}\n {}\n {}\n {}".format(ns_m3_testB.toon_tweets()[0], ns_m3_testB.toon_tweets()[1], ns_m3_testB.toon_tweets()[2], ns_m3_testB.toon_tweets()[3]),    
`